# CloudFoundry CLI login not working (Credentials were rejected, please try again)

Tags: authentication, jenkins, gradle, command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

So far I have always been able to log in successfully via sso.

```
cf login -a url --sso
```

I need another way to log in for my pipeline script and tried the following command.

```
cf login [-a API_URL] [-u USERNAME] [-p PASSWORD] [-o ORG] [-s SPACE]
```

This command does not work with my user, nor with a technical user to whom all necessary roles have been assigned (M D A). I get the following message.

```
API endpoint: url

Password>
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Or maybe an alternative to create a gradle task, for example, that can be executed in a jenkins pipeline. 
At the end, I want to automate a deploy (to cloud) of an artifact with my Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: possible reason could be multiple uaa origin existence
If your user isn't creating in default origin of uaa, you must then use cf auth command and provide the name of the origin as part of the authentication

Answer (score 1):

Using `--sso` and `-u`/`-p` are not doing the same thing on the backend, and there's no guarantee that a user which can login through SSO is also set up to login as a user stored directly in UAA. UAA has multiple origin's from which users can be loaded, like SAML, LDAP and internal to UAA. When you use the `--sso` flag, you are typically logging in via a user from your company's SAML provider. When you use the `-u`/`-p` flags, it's typically LDAP or UAA, something UAA validates directly.

In order for what you are trying to do to work, you would need to have a user available with an origin in SAML (for `--sso`) and a user in origin LDAP or UAA (internal), and technically those would be two separate users (despite the fact that they may have the same credentials).

At any rate, if you normally login with the `--sso` flag and you want to automate work, what you really want is to get a UAA client that is set with the grant type of client credentials. You can then use `cf auth CLIENT_ID CLIENT_SECRET --client-credentials` to automate logging in.

Typically you don't want your user account to be tied to pipelines and automated scripts anyway. If you leave the company and your user get deactivated then everything breaks :) You want a service account, and that is basically a client enabled with the client credentials grant type in UAA.

Answer (score 0):

You provided —sso flag, so you shouldn’t see a password prompt. Instead you should be given the url to get a token.

Maybe your CF has been misconfigured and does not support SSO yet. I tried to fix the CF CLI to avoid this but it was oddly rejected https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/pull/1624

Try fixing your CF installation (it needs to provide some prompts), or skip the —sso flag usage.